# While loop within another while loop is not working

Tags: javascript, php

I can not fetch data whithin a while loop which is another while loop.

```
<div class="row p_10" id="select_subject_div" style="display: none;">
  <?php
  $index_subjects_sql = "SELECT * FROM index_subjects";
  $index_subjects_result = mysqli_query($conn, $index_subjects_sql);
  while($index_subjects_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($index_subjects_result)) {
  ?>
    <div id="index_subject_item_div_<?=$index_subjects_data['subject_id']?>" style="width: 240px; position: relative; float: left;">

      <div class="p_5 border_1 bg_black" id="subject_color_palette_container_<?=$index_subjects_data['subject_id']?>" style="width: 350px; position: absolute; top: 100%; float: left; display: none; z-index: 1;">
        
        <?php
        $color_palettes_sql = "
        SELECT * FROM `index_color_palettes`";
        $color_palettes_result = mysqli_query($conn, $color_palettes_sql);
        while($color_palettes_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_palettes_result)) { 
        ?>
          <input type="button" id="choose_subject_color_button_<?=$color_palettes_data['color_palette_id']?>" style="background-color: <?=$color_palettes_data['color_hex_code']?>; border: none; width: 60px; height: 20px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" value="<?=$color_palettes_data['color_hex_code']?>" onclick="choose_subject_color_function_<?=$color_palettes_data['color_palette_id']?>()" >

          <script type="text/javascript">
          function choose_subject_color_function_<?=$color_palettes_data['color_palette_id']?>()
          {
            alert ("<?=$color_palettes_data['color_name']?>"); // PROBLEM - only the last item is coming
            alert ("<?=$index_subjects_data['subject_id']?>"); // PROBLEM - only the last item is coming
          }
          </script>
        <?php 
        }
        ?> <!-- ---------- Close While : color_palettes_data ---------- -->

      </div>
    </div> <!-- ---------- Close : index_subject_item_div_ ---------- -->
  <?php 
  } 
  ?> <!-- ---------- Close While : index_subjects_data ---------- -->
</div> <!-- ---------- Close : row ---------- -->
```

I can not fetch the data of -  which is within a while loop of "color_palettes_data" which is within another while loop "index_subjects_data"

alert (""); // PROBLEM - only the last item is coming

But I should get different subject id when I click on different button - choose_subject_color_button_....................

How can I get the value there within the function ?
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: What does "cannot" actually mean? Is there a specific error, or some unexpected output? What debugging have you done? We cannot run your code so you'll need to provide more info before we can usefully help you. See also [ask]

Comment: What ADyson said....but in taking a cursory look it could be variable scoping that's giving you problems. Additionally, double while loops are all a kind of a whonky approach generally speaking. Can you expand more on what's happening?

Comment: alert ("<?=$index_subjects_data['subject_id']?>"); // PROBLEM - only the last item is coming.

Comment: But I should get different subject id when I click on different button - choose_subject_color_button_....................

Comment: This is a JS issue or PHP? What does the rendered HTML and JS come out as?

Comment: I am getting only the last subject_id [ from here <?=$index_subjects_data['subject_id']?> ] every time when I click on the button

Comment: You've said the same thing +3 times. Please add details.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide extra information please instead of posting repetitive comments. Then it's clear, easily visible,  properly formatted and all in one place. This isn't a forum. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, since you are declaring the javascript function `choose_subject_color_function_()` in a `while` loop, only the last iteration will be kept for this function definition.

Here is what I mean:
The `while` loop while iterate over the data and recreate the `choose_subject_color_function_` function multiple times.
On each loop, you are passing a variable that will be set in the `alert` function.

Here is an visual overview of what's happening with the `alert()` value at each loop assuming that last iteration is at 10:

| Iterations | id | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01 | alert(01) |
| 1 | 02 | alert(02) |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 9 | 10 | alert(10) |
| 10 | 11 | alert(11) |

Hence, your alert will always output the `subject_id` of the last iteration of the `while` loop, such as `alert(11)`.

**Solution**

The solution to your problem resides in declaring your JS function outside of the `while` loops and passing the value you want to `alert` in the parameters of the function.

```
function choose_subject_color_function(subject_id) {
    alert(subject_id)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I checked that, But that time I am getting only the last value of "color_palettes_data" this while loop. By - alert ("<?=$color_palettes_data['color_name']?>"); - I added this line of code in original description, please check.

Comment: @Abhijit that sounds like the same logic problem, then. Pass the color name into the function the same way as the subject ID, as demonstrated in this answer

Comment: @Abhijit You did not apply the full solution in your edit. You need to move the <script> function choose_subject_color_function </script> OUTSIDE of both while loop. You should put the <script> block at the end of your last </div> for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're seeing is because of how PHP handles scoping.

You can try this code and let me know how it goes...

```
<div class="row p_10" id="select_subject_div" style="display: none;">
  <?php
  $index_subjects_sql = "SELECT * FROM index_subjects";
  $index_subjects_result = mysqli_query($conn, $index_subjects_sql);
  while ($index_subjects_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($index_subjects_result)) {
    ?>
    <div id="index_subject_item_div_<?=$index_subjects_data['subject_id']?>" style="width: 240px; position: relative; float: left;">
      <div class="p_5 border_1 bg_black" id="subject_color_palette_container_<?=$index_subjects_data['subject_id']?>" style="width: 350px; position: absolute; top: 100%; float: left; display: none; z-index: 1;">
        <?php
        $color_palettes_sql = "SELECT * FROM `index_color_palettes`";
        $color_palettes_result = mysqli_query($conn, $color_palettes_sql);
        while ($color_palettes_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($color_palettes_result)) {
          ?>
          <input type="button" id="choose_subject_color_button_<?=$color_palettes_data['color_palette_id']?>" style="background-color: <?=$color_palettes_data['color_hex_code']?>; border: none; width: 60px; height: 20px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" value="<?=$color_palettes_data['color_hex_code']?>" onclick="choose_subject_color_function('<?=$index_subjects_data['subject_id']?>')" >
          <?php 
        }
        ?> <!-- ---------- Close While : color_palettes_data ---------- -->
      </div>
    </div> <!-- ---------- Close : index_subject_item_div_ ---------- -->
    <?php 
  } 
  ?> <!-- ---------- Close While : index_subjects_data ---------- -->
</div> <!-- ---------- Close : row ---------- -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function choose_subject_color_function(subjectId) {
  alert(subjectId);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would affect PHP scope. There's only 1 level in this PHP script, there are no functions/classes.

Comment: @user3783243 There are actually 3 levels to the PHP scope here. The first one starting at line 2 with <?php tag. The second one starting at the 1st while loop and the third one starting at the 2nd while loop.  The problem in the initial question is indeed a scope problem between the definition of the JS function and the iteration of the while loops.

Comment: @XceeD Those are all the same scope level in PHP. A control block doesn't add scope. e.g. `if{}` doesn't change variable scope.. nor does `while`, `switch{}`, etc.

Comment: Those are all local 'scope level' if you want. That doesnt mean they are all in the same scope / accessible at the same level.

Comment: @XceeD They are... please provide an example of what you're trying to show.

Comment: @XceeD Here's example showing no change https://3v4l.org/JJEIo